# GWT compiler FileNotFoundException for permutation-0.js during linking

Tags: maven, jenkins, gwt, gxt

I have an intermittent issue while building a GWT application on my build server. Sometimes a build will fail with the following error:

> Unable to instantiate object java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /tmp/gwtc3983507944098316106.tmp/com.mycompany.mygwtapplication.mymodule/compiler/permutation-0.js
>   (No such file or directory)

I can see from the build log however that Permutation 0 sucessfully built. However, this directory in /tmp gets deleted so I can't verify if the file permutation-0.js file is actually present at link time. I have tried setting logLevel to DEBUG as suggested, but that led to the creation of 100GB log files per build, so it is unfortunately not practical. I am using GWT 2.7.0 and GXT 4.0.1. I am using Maven as my build tool, and Jenkins as my build server. This error does not occur when I build locally on my eclipse workstation with m2e. Since this only happens sometimes, I can't reliably replicate the issue. Building the same code over again will usually fix the issue, but we rely on the build server to be automated and consistent for our QA and support team. What could be causing this error? If needed, I could try freeing up the space for a debug output, but I'd like to exhaust other options first. The following is an example except from the build log:

```
...
[INFO] Compiling module com.mycompany.mygwtapplication.mymodule
[INFO]    Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
[INFO] Compile with -strict or with -logLevel set to TRACE or DEBUG to see all errors.
[INFO]    Compiling 42 permutations
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 0...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 1...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 2...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 3...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 4...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 5...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 6...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 7...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 8...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 9...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 10...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 11...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 12...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 13...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 14...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 15...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 16...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 17...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 18...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 19...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 20...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 21...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 22...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 23...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 24...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 25...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 26...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 27...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 28...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 29...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 30...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 31...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 32...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 33...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 34...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 35...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 36...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 37...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 38...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 39...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 40...
[INFO]       Compiling permutation 41...
[INFO]    Compile of permutations succeeded
[INFO]    Compilation succeeded -- 181.222s
[INFO] Linking into /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/MyGWTModule-CI/target/myapplication-webcontent/login
[INFO]    [ERROR] Unable to instantiate object
[INFO] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/gwtc4151238126548020139.tmp/com.mycompany.mygwtapplication.mymodule/compiler/permutation-0.js (No such file or directory)
[INFO]  at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
[INFO]  at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
[INFO]  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.Util.readFileAsObject(Util.java:667)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.FileBackedObject.newInstance(FileBackedObject.java:74)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.util.FileBackedObject.newInstance(FileBackedObject.java:32)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.finishPermutation(Link.java:479)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.doSimulatedShardingLink(Link.java:450)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Link.link(Link.java:182)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:246)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.run(Compiler.java:158)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler$1.run(Compiler.java:120)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.doRun(CompileTaskRunner.java:55)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.CompileTaskRunner.runWithAppropriateLogger(CompileTaskRunner.java:50)
[INFO]  at com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler.main(Compiler.java:127)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 03:29 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-12T14:09:02-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 62M/733M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

Comment: you have one error in your build. set the logLevel to TRACE to find the error.

Comment: Or, if TRACE is too hard to read, enabled strict mode so it fails on the first error.

Comment: How do you have 42 permutations? Also give it extra memory, it always helps.

Comment: I've added strict mode and set the log level to TRACE. I will have to manually clear out the logs while this is set, but I hope to catch the failure in the act this way, "unfortunately" the builds have been working the past few days so hopefully I will be able to catch the error before I have to do too much housekeeping on the server to prevent the logs from filling it up.

Comment: @LuigiPolvani that's how many permutations get built using the default user.agent and gxt.user.agent settings. There would probably be fewer if we restricted this, but our product manager has not decided if we want to limit the supported browsers.

Comment: @ElHoss well setting trace logging and strict mode has helped a lot! I discovered a lot of server side code that was being referenced in the client side, and managed to refactor it all out. Now I have no errors in the gwt compilation, and I'm not getting the FileNotFound error on the last 3 builds. If you make this an answer I will mark it as solved. TRACE logging also used a lot less disk space than DEBUG - by several orders of magnitude, and strict mode has also helped a lot, thanks @ColinAlworth!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you see something like that in the console output:

```
Ignored 1 unit with compilation errors in first pass.
```

the GWT compiles fails with one or more errors. To get more informations about the error add:

```
-logLevel TRACE
```

or

```
-strict
```

(as Colin mentioned) to your DevMode arguments.

Using `-strict` will force the compiler to stop, once an error occurs.
Using `-logLevel TRACE` will produce information where the error occurs. Search for 'ERROR' to find all errors inside the console output.

If your are using eclipse, make sure, that you have unchecked the 'Limit consule output' to see all messages.

[image]